# Sync folders with xcopy/batch based on checksum?

Tags: batch-file, synchronization, md5, checksum, xcopy

I'm trying to make a simple batch for windows that will basically sync two folders, the catch is that the files in the folders can be named arbitrarily and the snyc should be based on the checksum. I've only found information about xcopy that compares the timestamp so I'm wondering if this is possible in a simple matter at all.

Here is the scenario I'm trying to manage, you've got the "Import Folder" containing the files named A_2.bmp and A_3.bmp and the "Target Folder" containing file A_1.bmp.
File A_2.bmp is infact the same file as A_1.bmp, just with a different name and thus should be skipped, A_3.bmp should then be copied over to target folder and icrementally renamed to A_2.bmp.

This probably sounds more like a work for patching software, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require building patches all the time and is open for the user (so he can just drop files into the import folder and run it whenever the need arises)

If there is software for such a thing that is free and can be distributed without installing I would also consider this a good option, but I haven't found anything.

I'm thankful for any advice and help on this matter so thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

You have this command line utility :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533

You can then make a bat who simply test the checksum of the files

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm already experimenting with this https://www.fourmilab.ch/md5/ which doesn't require an install on the user end.